# Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: number

Tags: react-native, expo

After I added web support to my expo react-native project I started getting errors while navigating to my login or register screens. other screen works perfectly but when I try to navigate to my login screen I get this error

`Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: number`

I still don't understand what could be causing this because a few days ago it was working fine maybe something changed that I don't know about please help me look at my code.

this is my login screen

```
    import React, { Component, useState } from 'react'
import { SafeAreaView, Button, TextInput, View, Text, 
  TouchableOpacity, Alert, KeyboardAvoidingView } from 'react-native'

import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';


import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'

import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword, sendPasswordResetEmail,
   setPersistence, inMemoryPersistence, reactNativeLocalPersistence,browserSessionPersistence,
   Persistence,} from 'firebase/auth';

import MateriaIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons'
import MateriaIonicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'

import LogingImg from '../assets/images/LoginImg.svg'

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import ProgressBar from './ProgressBar';
//import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation'
import KeyboardWraper from './KeyboardWraper';


export class Login extends Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);
        
       this.state = {
        email: '',
        password: '',
        logingPending: false,
        //userData: {}
       }
       this.onSignIn = this.onSignIn.bind(this)
       this.onResetPassword = this.onResetPassword.bind(this)
    };

     async setPersistence(persistence) {
      const  Persistence = persistence
        ? browserSessionPersistence
        : inMemoryPersistence;
  
      await setPersistence(this.auth, type);
    }

    onResetPassword() {
      const auth = getAuth();
      const { email, password, logingPending } = this.state
      if(email.trim().length == 0){
        Alert.alert(
          "",
          "please provide your email ",
          [
            
            { text: "OK", onPress: () => this.setState({logingPending:false}) }
          ])
      }else {
sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, email)
  .then(() => {
    console.log ('')

    Alert.alert(
      "",
      "Password reset email sent to ",
      [
        
        { text: "OK", onPress: () => this.setState({logingPending:false}) }
      ])
    // ..
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;

    Alert.alert(
      "",
      error.message,
      [
        
        { text: "OK", onPress: () => this.setState({logingPending:false}) }
      ])
    
    // ..
  });
 }}


    onSignIn(props) {
        const auth = getAuth();
          const { email, password, logingPending } = this.state
          //logingPending: true

          if(email.trim().length == 0 && password.trim.length == 0){
            this.setState({logingPending:false})
            Alert.alert(
              "",
              "Fields can't be empty",
              [
                
                { text: "OK", onPress: () => this.setState({logingPending:false}) }
              ])
            //return
         }else {


          signInWithEmailAndPassword( auth, email, password)
          .then((result) => {

            this.setState({logingPending:false})
            this.props.navigation.goBack()
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)


           Alert.alert(
               "Login Error",
                 'Please confirm your details',
                 [
        
                    { text: "OK", onPress: () => this.setState({logingPending:false}) }
                ])   
            this.setState({logingPending:false})
            //Alert.alert(error)
            
          })
        } 
    }

    async storeToken(user) {
      try {
         await AsyncStorage.setItem("userData", JSON.stringify(user));
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Something went wrong", error);
      }
    }
    

  render() {
    return (
      <KeyboardWraper>
      <SafeAreaView style = {{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <View style={{paddingHorizontal: 25 }}>
        <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <LogingImg  width={300} height={300} />

        </View>

        <Text style = {{fontSize: 20, fontWeight: '500', color: 'green', marginBottom: 30}}> Login </Text>


          <View style={{
            flexDirection: 'row',
            borderBottomColor: '#ccc',
            borderBottomWidth: 1,
            paddingBottom:8,
            marginBottom: 25
        }}>
            <MateriaIcons name='email' size={20} color='#666' style={{marginLeft: 5}} />
            <TextInput placeholder='email address' autoCorrect={false} onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({email})} style={{ flex:1, paddingVertical: 0, marginLeft: 5}} 
            keyboardType ='email-address'
            />
          </View>

          <View style={{
            flexDirection: 'row',
            borderBottomColor: '#ccc',
            borderBottomWidth: 1,
            paddingBottom:8,
            marginBottom: 25,
        }}>
            <MateriaIonicons name='ios-lock-closed-outline' size={20} color='#666' style={{marginLeft: 5}} />
            <TextInput placeholder='password' autoCapitalize={false} autoCorrect={false} onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})} secureTextEntry= {true} style={{
               flex:1, 
               paddingVertical: 0, marginLeft: 5,
              
              }} />
            
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.onResetPassword()}}>
              <Text style ={{color: 'red'}}> Forgot </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            </View>

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.onSignIn(), this.setState({logingPending:true})} } style = {{
              backgroundColor: 'green',
              padding: 20,
              borderRadius: 10,
              marginBottom: 20
            }}>
              <Text style={{textAlign: 'center', fontWeight: '700', fontSize: 16, color: '#fff'}}> Login </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>

          <View style = {{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center', marginBottom: 30}}>
          <Text>
            Not yet a customer?
          </Text>

          <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate("Register")
          }}>
            <Text style={{color: 'green', fontWeight: '700'}}> JOIN!</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          {this.state.logingPending ? <ProgressBar /> : null}
      </SafeAreaView>
      </KeyboardWraper>
    )
  }
}

export default Login
```

then it says I should Check the render method of `Login`.